# A Question on Showing that a vector is a member of a coset

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Let $x,n_i,w$ be vectors in a vector space $X$ and $N$ be a subspace of $X$. $A_x = \{w \, | \, w = x + n_i, n_i \in N\}$ are the cosets of $N$. I want to show that if $v \in X$ then $v$ must be in one of the cosets. So I write: $v = v - n_1 + n_1$. If I let $y = v - n_1$ then $v \in A_y$. I'm worried though that this depended on the choice of $n_1$. Suppose I took $n_1 \neq n_2$ then $$v -n_1 \neq v- n_2 \implies y \neq v- n_2$$
So now for a different choice of $n_i$ I have that $v \notin A_y$. This doesn't seem correct. Shouldn't I have that $v$ is a member of the same coset, regardless of representative I choose for $n_i \in N$?

Comment: $A_x = x + N$, hence $v \in A_v$ because $v = v + 0$ and $0 \in N$.

Comment: This is not clear.  How many $n_i$ are there?  If you want a coset, you should let the $n_i$ span *all* of the vectors in $N$, not just a handful.  Indexing the $n_i$ the way you do, suggests a finite or at least countable selection, but that's not what you intend, right?

Comment: What @BotnakovN. wrote.

Comment: Whatever equivalence relation you consider on a set $X$, an element $v\in X$ will *always* belong to one of the equivalence classes: its own class, by definition.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest there is a finite or countable set of $n_i$ -- I meant just to choose a vector from a subspace $N$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. But also $v = v - n + n$ with $n \in N$, so isn't $v \in A_{v - n}$ as well? But $v$ should only be in one coset.

Comment: If $n\in N$ then $A_{v-n}=A_v.$ Otherly said: if $w\in A_v,$ then $A_w=A_v.$ This is true for *every* equivalence relation $\sim:$ $x\sim y\iff[x]=[y]\iff x\in[y].$

Comment: What you write is very hard to follow.  You aren't choosing a vector from $N$, rather you want to consider *all* of them.   Thus, for a fixed vector $x$, $A_x$ is the collection of every vector of the form $x+n$ where $n\in N$.  In particular, for $n_0$ a particular vector in $N$, $A_x$ is always the same as $A_{x-n_0}$.  This is how cosets work generally...either they are disjoint or they coincide.

Comment: @yoshi $A_{v-n} = A_v$ for any $n \in N$ hence there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's the equivalence relation $[a]=[b]\Rightarrow A_a=A_b (a,b\in V)$, hence $v-n_2\neq v-n_1=y$ doesn't lead to $v\not\in A_y$. As you can see, $A_{v-n_1}=A_{v-n_2}$, since $A_{v-n_1}\ni (v-n_1)+\underset{\in N}{\underbrace{n_0}}=(v-n_2)+\underset{\in N}{\underbrace{(n_2-n_1+n_0)}}\in A_{v-n_2} (\forall n_0\in N)$ and vice versa.